# Перевернуть все элементы списка задом наперёд

Tags: python, list

Пользователь вводит текст, который переводится в список. Нужно, чтобы каждый элемент был выведен задом наперёд.

Например, пользователь ввёл: "я люблю свою собаку",
нужно получить список: ['я', 'юлбюл', 'юовс', 'укабос']

Написал эти строки кода:

```
lines = input().split()
lines[::-1]
print(lines)
```

но он мне просто разворачивает список...

Comment: Надо пройтись по каждому слову в списке значит....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используя срез всего списка `lines[::-1]` вы не меняете самих элементов.
Пройдитесь по нему, разворачивая каждую встретившуюся строку:

```
lines = input().split()
new_lines = [i[::-1] for i in lines]
```

после этого в `new_lines`:

```
>>> new_lines
['я', 'юлбюл', 'юовс', 'укабос']
```

Answer (score 4):

Альтернативный вариант:

```
lines = ['я', 'люблю', 'свою', 'собаку']
lines = list(map(lambda el: ''.join(reversed(el)), lines))
```